# I have three load cells can I sum all the three into Arduino to be one output? If yes how?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, power, usb, performance

I am doing stand thrust and I have three load cells to measure the force. I would like to know if I can sum them to gather into the Arduino or I should use a junction box.

Comment: Arithmetics is easier than mechanics and electronics. But perhaps that's just because I do not know `load cells` nor `junction boxes`.

Comment: Do you *really* want to *sum* them (the total of the forces applied to each), or do you really want to *average* them (the average load applied across the whole surface)...? The answer is "yes" in both cases, but you will have to build the right kind of circuit to perform the operation you want - and that will take multiple op-amps to do the job. Simpler to connect each direct with a HX711 each and do maths in code.